# jest cannot find components in our repository

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs, babeljs, repository

jest cannot find components in our repository. Our app works fine however, this is the error we get:

FAIL  src/components/dataconnectivitynew/ConnectionName/connectionName.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/Users/mng/Documents/ssnc/ds-ui-react/node_modules/@xxxx/ui-shared-library/dist/index.js:12
import require$$2, { jsx, jsxs, Fragment } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

   5 | import SQL from "../../../assets/images/sql-database.svg";
   6 | import NoSQL from "../../../assets/images/nosql-database.svg";
>  7 | import { Button } from "@xxxx/ui-shared-library";
     | ^
   8 | import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
   9 | import { Header } from "../../../components/dataconnectivitynew/subcomponents/Header/Header";
  10 | import { ConnectionCard } from "../ConnectionCard/connectionCard";

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/Connections/NewDataConnection/newDataConnection.js:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:13:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/testUtils.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/dataconnectivitynew/ConnectionName/connectionName.test.js:2:1)
```

In the shared library package json we have this:

```
{
  "name": "@xxxx/ui-shared-library",
  "version": "1.0.36",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "private": false,
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "classnames": "^2.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "@floating-ui/react-dom": "^2.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rollup src/App.tsx --format iife --name ui-shared-library --file bundle.js ",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "plugin:storybook/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://artifactory.ssnc.dev/artifactory/api/npm/xxxxmarketplace-npm-local/"
  },
  "strict-ssl": false,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.17",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "20.11.16",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "prettier": "3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "rollup": "^4.9.6",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-sass": "^1.12.21",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript": "^1.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.36.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "storybook": "^7.5.3",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "4.8",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know where this error can be coming from?

Comment: You publish your lib as esm but run jest as common js. Publish your lib as dual package or run jest in esm or try `transformIgnorePatterns` in your jest config.

Comment: If my lib package json has type: module its a esm right? How do I run jest as commonjs? transformIgnorePatterns doesn't work for me because I'm using CRA